# Reorder an HTML element based on a condition?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress loads a banner before 'page-wrap' if on a certain page.

The banner is loaded by including a file 'header.php'

However, I'd like to load it after 'main-wrap' if it's on a different page.

```
 <body> 

    <div id="page-wrap">

      <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="main-header">

        <?php include ("./../included/header.php"); ?>
    </div>

 </div>
```

I would like to note I solved the problem by creating a conditional statement which includes an alternate header2.php file. So, problem solved by two separate files.

Comment: so you only only like to show the header.php when certain conditions are true ?

Comment: Use an `if else` statement.

Comment: You don't explain what's the problem you are facing, besides the fact it has to be placed only when a condition is met. On the other hand, ¿what do you mean by `load it just after the body tag`. Load it inside the body or load it after the body's closing tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` statements. Use two statements so that you don't get duplicate banners.

```
<body> 
   <?php
   if( yourcondition ){
     include ("./../included/header.php");
   }
   ?>
    <div id="page-wrap">

      <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="main-header">

   <?php
   if( yourcondition ){
     include ("./../included/header.php");
   }
   ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use just `if..else...` like this

```
<div id="main-header">
    <?php 
     if(condition) {
         include ("./../included/header.php"); 
     }
     ?>
</div>
```